# How to extend Fragment and Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there a way to extend Fragment and Activity together?

```
class MyEditorFragment extends Fragment implements TextStuff,
    Stuff2Listener, OnClickListener<Cursor>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take note of this: There is no way to subclass more than one superclass at a time.

Besides, Fragment is actually a mini activity itself, which can be associated with a parent activity. You might want to refer to the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) as it provides clear explanation.

Additionally:

*Take note that Fragment article is sub-listed under Activity in the documentation*

Answer (score 1):

Umm i think not, why would you want to do that?. They are totally different thing with different life cycle. A fragment has to be attached to an activity. However your Activity should extend FragmentActivity.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure about this. Am still learning Android Dev :)